# Can I store raw gnocchi dough in the fridge?

Tags: pasta, dough, italian-cuisine, gnocchi

I made gnocchi dough earlier this evening. It was my first time, so I took a bit of dough and made myself some dinner with it. It was great.

But I still have some dough left over. Since it's quite late: can I store it in the fridge and continue making gnocchi tomorrow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dough should keep for around a week in the fridge before changing texture, in my experience.  So a day should be fine.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, gnocchi store well in the fridge for a day or so, or in the freezer for longer term storage. It's best to try and keep the gnocchi separate (placing on a baking sheet or tray is best) so they don't stick together, and very well covered so that they don't absorb any odours in your fridge.

If freezing, freeze on the tray until reasonably hard, and you can then transfer them to a tub or bag.

Comment: Just to expand: if you freeze them, freeze the already formed gnocchi. Do not freeze the dough ball, in my experience it was disastrous to try and make gnocchi out of it (still tasted ok, but the handling was very messy).

Answer (score 0):

Yes but from my experiance they only keep for 3 days in the fridge.